# Ошибка C2280 при работе с мьютексом

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Компилятор VS2013 пишет следующее:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\chrono(173): error C2280: 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function 
>  1>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\mutex(113) : see declaration of 'std::mutex::mutex' 
>  1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function
>   'CThreadedCircular::CThreadedCircular(const CThreadedCircular &)'

Вот описание класса, в котором возникла эта ошибка:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

class CThreadedCircular
{
public:

    CThreadedCircular(size_t sz) : buffer_(sz){ ; }
    ~CThreadedCircular(){ free(); }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    void push(SHP_CAVPacket val)
    {
        mutex_.lock();
        buffer_.push_back(val);
        mutex_.unlock();
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    SHP_CAVPacket pop()
    {
        SHP_CAVPacket retVal;
        mutex_.lock();
        retVal = buffer_.front();
        buffer_.pop_front();
        mutex_.unlock();
        return retVal;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    int size()
    {
        int s;
        mutex_.lock();
        s = buffer_.size();
        mutex_.unlock();
        return s;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    void free()
    {
        mutex_.lock();
        buffer_.clear();
        mutex_.unlock();
    }
private:
    std::mutex  mutex_;
    boost::circular_buffer<SHP_CAVPacket>   buffer_;
};
```

Из-за чего она возникла и как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не предоставляете свою реализацию конструктора копирования, поэтому компилятор пытается сделать это за вас. В этом конструкторе происходит попытка копирования мьютекса, который является non-copyable. Из-за этого и возникает ошибка.

Для её устранения реализуйте конструктор копирования в `CThreadedCircular`.